# get HTML value [swift]

Tags: html, swift

I have this set of html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="panel panel-default ">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form id="coupon_checkout" action="http://uat.all.com.my/checkout/couponcode" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="transaction_id" value="4245">
            <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="EN">
            <input type="hidden" name="devicetype" value="">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="coupon_code" name="coupon" placeholder="Coupon Code">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enter Code</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the transaction id value. How do i get it?
I have try using this code:

```
var value = wkWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementByName('transaction_id')", completionHandler: nil)

print("value:\(value)")
```

But the output is return nothing:

value:( )

Answer (score 1):

Two things - you need an "s" in the getElementsByName code and it returns a collection of elements - you need to specify which - in this case there is only 1, but you still need to specify it and get the value of the element:

```
...document.getElementsByName('transaction_id')[0].value....
```

Comment: I don't know swift at all - but normally i would expect you to get the value - it seems to me as if you are getting the element but not the value of the lements - try ...document.getElementsByName('transaction_id')[0].value ....

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a typo, you should use `getElementsByName` instead of `getElementByName`.

Second thing:
Shouldn't it be `"document.getElementsByName('transaction_id').value"` rather than `"document.getElementByName('transaction_id')"`

You can also use it like if heaving issues:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByName('someElement').value") { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(result)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ha - Ha  - @Pravesh Agrawal - already posted that - its a race with these answers :)

Comment: ha ha - @Pravesh Agrawal - this time you got there ahead of me - i posted my answer re - the .value and then saw your edited answer saying the same thing :) - but you still need the [0] in there to specify which element in the collection to reference

Answer (score 0):

I have just popped it into this snippet and provided the value in a jquery approach (since you are using Bootstrap - you must also be using jQuery) and the normal javascript method - both work so it must be something to do with the swift content. - also in your output - are you sure that the "\" is not escaping the "("? - should it be print("value:(value)") or escape both print("value:`\`(value`\`)") or alter the quotes print("value:"(value))

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var transaction_idValue1 = $('[name=transaction_id]').val();
  console.log(transaction_idValue1);
  
 var transaction_idValue2 = document.getElementsByName('transaction_id')[0].value;
  console.log(transaction_idValue2);
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="panel panel-default ">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form id="coupon_checkout" action="http://uat.all.com.my/checkout/couponcode" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="transaction_id" value="4245">
                    <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="EN">
                    <input type="hidden" name="devicetype" value="">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="coupon_code" name="coupon" placeholder="Coupon Code">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enter Code</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup)

```
let html = "<div class=\"container-fluid\">"
    + "<div class=\"panel panel-default \">"
    + "<div class=\"panel-body\">"
    + "<form id=\"coupon_checkout\" action=\"http://uat.all.com.my/checkout/couponcode\" method=\"post\">"
    + "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"transaction_id\" value=\"4245\">"
    + "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"lang\" value=\"EN\">"
    + "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"devicetype\" value=\"\">"
    + "<div class=\"input-group\">"
    + "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"coupon_code\" name=\"coupon\" placeholder=\"Coupon Code\">"
    + "<span class=\"input-group-btn\">"
    + "<button class=\"btn btn-primary\" type=\"submit\">Enter Code</button>"
    + "</span>"
    + "</div>"
    + "</form>"
    + "</div>"
    + "</div>"
let document: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html);//parse html
let elements = try document.select("[name=transaction_id]")//query
let transaction_id = try elements.get(0)//select first element , 
let value = try transaction_id.val()//get value
print(value)//4245
```